# 3 phase panel 480/277 volt then one of breaker goes to transfer then to panel 120/208 V can I add sub panel from 120/208 panel? Get 120/208 panel?

Tags: electrical

I trying to get another panel from all of this? From main panel to transfer to smaller panel. Need to end up with a 120/208 volt panel.

Comment: Most home owners do not use 480/277 power systems, so most of these systems need to have work on them done by a licensed electrician, instead of an owner or some guy the owner asks to do the work.

Comment: This desperately needs some more detail. What is it you're trying to accomplish? This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean 277/480/3ph to a transformer that steps it down to 120/208/3ph. From there, you can get a sub panel that's 120/208/3ph or a subpanel that's 120/208/1ph, which would be two 120 volt to neutral legs and 208 volt phase to phase. Doing this would depend on the size of the transformer. This is normally the type of service for high-rise residential buildings or multi-occupancy buildings and would probably require a professional. This wouldn't normally be considered DIY work.

Comment: Thank you yes this is on older warehouse that was made into a apartment complex.  But yes  one contractor said it could not be done and one said it could. Thank you.